# Creating a wait using getTickCount in Delphi

Tags: delphi, timer, wait, gettickcount

I am creating a procedure that I need to run then wait 10 minutes before moving on

```
procedure firstTimeRun(const document: IHTMLDocument2);
var
  fieldValue : string;
  StartTime : Dword;
begin
  StartTime := GetTickCount();
  WebFormSetFieldValue(document, 0, 'Username', '*******');
  WebFormSetFieldValue(document, 0, 'Password', '*******');
  WebFormSubmit(document, 0);
 if (GetTickCount() >= StartTime+ 600000) then
 begin
   SecondRun();
 end; 
 end;
```

the problem I have is when I get to the if statement it will check see that it is not true and move on how do I make it stay and wait until the statement is true?

Comment: Can't you use a TTimer?

Comment: Note, that if you run this in a main thread, it will block the UI (for 10 minutes!). If that is so, do not use the proposed way nor try to "fix" that block by calling `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naively the answer is that you need a `while` loop:

```
while GetTickCount() < StartTime+600000 then
  ;
SecondRun();
```

Or perhaps more easily read, a `repeat` loop:

```
repeat
until GetTickCount() >= StartTime+600000;
SecondRun();
```

But that's the wrong way to do it. You'll run the processor hot for 10 minutes, and achieve nothing. And I'm glossing over the fact that if your system has been up for 49 days then you'll hit `GetTickCount` wrap-around and the logic of the test is then flawed.

The operating system has a function designed to solve your problem, it is called [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298.aspx).

```
Sleep(600000);
```

This blocks the calling thread for the specified number of milliseconds. Because the thread is blocks, the thread will not consume CPU resource while it is waiting.

This will make the calling thread unresponsive, so it's typically something that you would do in a background thread rather than an application's main thread.

Comment: I had been looking at sleep but there seams to be a lot of people hesitant to ever use it that was why I asked.

Comment: Well, it is very very widely mis-used. But it's perfect if you really do need to wait a lengthy amount of time, and want to block. Often useful in a background thread for keep alive timers where you did not want to run a message queue. In your case, avoiding sleep, but replacing it with a busy loop would equally well raise the wrath of the people that don't like sleep. And I personally am one of the sleep haters, but only when it is mis-used.

Comment: The reason people mis-use it is because they just want something solved and don't want to think about the whole context of the problem with blocking calls in Windows applications.  The OP's question suggests he's just such a person.

Comment: @WarrenP GUI programs don't typically block for 10 minutes.

Comment: @David I can't imagine any part of any program, where it would make sense to **block** something for 10 minutes - just to close such an application can keep you waiting for 10 minutes in worst case :o)

Comment: @Sir No. You can close such an app without problem. A blocked thread doesn't stop an app from closing.

Comment: @David, but blocks a thread for terminating. 10 minutes is really long time to `Sleep`.

Comment: @TLama blocked background  thread doesn't block termination. ExitProcess gets the job done.

Comment: @David, I don't mean when you're terminating application. There it's fine. I wouldn't like to have in my running application, let's say 10 threads with the `Terminated` flag set sleeping for so long when I wanted to `Terminate` them.

Comment: @TLama Then you'd use an event to cancel the wait